# socket.io - not able to install

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have to install `socket.io` in corporate network. Please find below the values set in `.npmrc`.

```
proxy = http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8080
https-proxy = http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8080
registry = http://registry.npmjs.org/
strict-ssl = false
```

I've installed `express`, `grunt` and `bower` with same settings. When I execute `npm install socket.io`, I am getting below error.

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/rase-/node-XMLHttpRequest/archive/a6b6f
2.tar.gz
npm http GET https://github.com/rase-/node-XMLHttpRequest/archive/a6b6f2.tar.gz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/rase-/node-XMLHttpRequest/archive/a6b6f
2.tar.gz
unbuild engine.io-client@1.5.2
unbuild socket.io-client@1.3.6
unbuild socket.io@1.3.6
npm ERR! Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\
node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:159:17)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:175:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1569:9)
npm ERR!     at TCP.onread (net.js:525:27)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\xxx\Socket_POC
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.13
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.2
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\Socket_POC\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I couldn't figure out why is it going to `github` to fetch the data.
Still I tried to run below code of `index.js` with `node` and getting an error:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

/*app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});*/

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'engine.io'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js
:9:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Even I installed `engine.io` but still couldn't able to install `socket.io`.

**How to resolve this issue with `socket.io` installation ???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`engine.io-client`, a dependency, is pulling a [version](https://github.com/rase-/node-XMLHttpRequest/tree/add/ssl-support) of `XMLHttpRequest` [directly from github.com](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client/blob/1.5.2/package.json#L35) not the npm registry. Is your corporate proxy blocking you from downloading stuff on github?

If so, you won't be able to install until they merge and push this branch of `XMLHttpRequest` to the npm registry.

Answer (score 0):

I see it's old question, but I've just stumbled on the same thing.

If you really need to use this version of socket.io (update of the socket.io would simply solve it since it uses newer version of engine.io-client).

There is one way to override internal dependencies. You can use [npm shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap). 
You define file called npm-shrinkwrap.json and inside define that your dependency (in your case socket.io) uses different internal dependency(in your case engine.io-client).

```
{
  "name": "<your_package>",
  "version": "<your_package_version>",
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io": {
      "version": "1.5.2", 
      "from": "socket.io@1.5.2",
      "dependencies": {
        "engine.io-client": {
          "version": "1.6.4", //this one does not have issue with external download
          "from": "engine.io-client@1.6.4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, make sure that inside your package.json you put

"engine.io-client" : 1.6.4